# Como criar uma tabela com crosstab no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela `tbexame` e quero criar uma outra a partir de um crosstab, ao estudar fiz a instalação da extensão mas não estou conseguindo criar um select de maneira de deixar o resultado da seguinte forma:

tabela crosstab:

```
paciente_id, parametro_exame_1, parametro_exame_2, ... ,parametro_exame_x
1, positivo, positivo, ...,parametro_exame_x
2, positivo, positivo, ...,parametro_exame_x
...
x, positivo, positivo, ...,parametro_exame_x
```

tabela original:

```
paciente_id, exame, valor
1, parametro_exame_1, positivo
1, parametro_exame_2, positivo
...
x, parametro_exame_x, positivo
```

Código do select crosstab:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT paciente_id, parametro_exame_1
       FROM   tbexame
       ORDER BY paciente_id ASC'
   ) AS ct (paciente_id character varying, exame TEXT);
```

Erro:

```
return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601
```

Obs: Não se sabe o valor de `x`

Outra forma que tentei foi:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT DISTINCT paciente_id, exame, resultado FROM tbexame ORDER BY paciente_id'
   ) AS ct (paciente_id character varying, exame character varying, resultado character varying);
```

Mas o resultado foi uma coluna exame e outra resultado. E na verdade queria que cada parâmetro fosse uma coluna e o resultado como atributo.

Comment: Se você souber o valor de `x` então veja a função crosstab_N_ senão utilize `crosstab(text source_sql, text category_sql)` e em `category_sql` relacione os parâmetros de exame possíveis. Veja exemplo na documentação (F.38.1.4.).

Comment: Você pode fazer um `SELECT DISTINCT exame FROM sua_tabela ORDER BY exame` e obter a relação dos parametros_exame_n.

Comment: Siim o problema é que a relação de parâmetro será muito grande.

Comment: Mas, pelo que entendi, esta relação não são as colunas que deseja na sua saída?

Comment: Quero que exista a coluna paciente_id e uma coluna para cada parametro_exame.